# What the right way to access memory mapped register is?

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, driver

I'm new to developing device driver, but I've run into trouble shortly after starting.

I'm making *Intel High Definition Audio Controller driver*, and I checked in the specification that the access on the memory mapped register would be necessary.

I found their addresses using *devmgmt.msc* and *RWEverything*, they're started at `0xF7FF8000`.

When I wrote `DriverEntry`, I directly accessed that base address(e.g. `(unsigned char*)0xf7ff8000`) and used index and offset to access specific register, but when I started driver, **BSOD** occured at the point I read a value from one of them register(It was `CorbSize` register on offset `0x4e`)

BSOD stop code was `0x00000050, "PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA"`. And kd showed me that `f7ff8000` is freed (or corrupted) pool and there's Bad allocation size `@f7ff8000`, too large...

Are those error codes mean that address 0xF7FF8000 is unavailable data space?
But I checked the contents on 0xF7FF8000 using *RWEverything*, 
and there were constantly changing values on that space, even though db 0xf7ff8000 command on kd showed me only ??-filled memory space...

I really wonder what the problem is, and what the right way to access their memory mapped registers is.

Sorry for my bad english skill :'(

Thanks!

Comment: It most probably is PCI mapped memory at 0xf7ff8000 *physical*, and you're writing to a virtual address. Even then, you must use a `volatile` l-value to write to these!

Comment: Thanks for comment! I tried just before, like \*((volatile unsigned int\*)0xf7ff8000), but it didn't work and same BSOD occurred again.

Comment: Of course it didn't work because you're accessing a virtual address and not a physical.  The **operating system** you're targetting is relevant information here by the way, not "audio" or "osdev".

Comment: @Liddel There's a lot of details you need to do right when writing a kernel driver for windows - a lot more than kan simply be answered here without more specific details. Start reading https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/wdf/reading-and-writing-to-device-registers and then https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/wdf/reading-and-writing-to-device-registers and make sure you have set up all the details properly before you start accessing device memory. Even the links above will require that you already have a solid foundation of the windows kernel.